# React Navigation Reset Stack Navigator which is sub navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a TabNavigator which is created by `createBottomTabNavigator`

```
createBottomTabNavigator({
    Tab1: View1,
    Tab2: createStackNavigator({
        SubScreen1: View2,
        SubScreen2: View3
    }),
    Tab3: createStackNavigator({
        SubScreen3: View4,
        SubScreen4: View5,
        SubScreen5: View6
    }),

})
```

And now lets say i'm on `Tab3`, doing some stuff on `SubScreen3` then press `next`, the same for `SubScreen4`, `next`, And now i'm on `Tab3/SubScreen5` and i want to `this.props.navigation.navigate('Subscreen 2')` which is working fine, but when i go to `Tab3` again it is still on `SubScreen5`.

What is want is to reset `Tab3` back to `SubScreen3` every time i go to some other tab.

I've tried to

```
navigation.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset(
      {
          index:0, 
          actions:[NavigationActions.navigate('SubScreen2')]
       })
);
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Try to add `key: null` after `index`

Comment: yeah,  i did. But for some reason react-navigation says that it doesn't know rout SubScreen2, even it is registered. I think there is some trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because SubScreen2 is not in the stack yet. Try this.

```
navigation.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset(
      {
          index:0, 
          key: null,
          actions:[NavigationActions.navigate({
              routeName: 'Tab2',
              action: NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'SubScreen2'})
          })]
       })
);
```